# Horizontal matrix - How to make fixed-width without paddings and having a break between values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a matrix in SSRS 2008 like:

```
Teacher [TeacherName]
# of Students [Count(studentId)]
```

[image]

What I want is to fix the width of the column. I am changing the padding values but the spaces are not going away.

1. How can I get rid of the empty spaces for the cells
2. How can I put a break (like \n) between name and surname? (instead of comma)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression for the TeacherName  input:

=Fields!YourColumn.Value.ToString().Replace(",",vbCrLf)